# Appending AJAX response to element by id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add some radio buttons from an AJAX response to a `<div>` on my page but am having trouble with it inserting the correct HTML. The code looks like this:

```
// AJAX form for updating tests after category has been selected

$('#categories').change(function(){
    category_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{% url 'test-list-update' %}",
        data: {"category_id": category_id},
        success: function(response){

            console.log(response.tests[0]);

            $.each(response.tests, function(index, title){
                var tests = $('#test_list');
                tests.append($('<div>', { class : 'form-check' }));
                tests.prepend($('<input>', { type : 'checkbox', class : 'form-check-input', value : index }));
                tests.append($('<label>', { class : 'form-check-label' })).text(title);
            });
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response.tests[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

My goal is to have my HTML look like this:

```
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="tests" id="id_tests_1" value="271"> // value = response.index
        <label class="form-check-label" for="id_tests_1">
            This is the title from the response
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="test" id="id_tests_2" value="276">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="id_tests_2">
            This is the second title from the response
        </label>
    </div>
```

This doesn't seem to be happening though. How should it look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the AJAX request is working and returning data in the format you expect, then the issue with building the HTML is because you're always appending/prepending to `#test_list` instead of nesting the new elements as your example output shows. As such, try this:

```
let $tests = $('#test_list'); // note: this is outside the loop

$.each(response.tests, function(index, title) {
  let $div = $('<div>', { class : 'form-check' }).appendTo($tests);
  $('<input>', { type : 'checkbox', class : 'form-check-input', value : index })).appendTo($div);
  $('<label>', { class : 'form-check-label' }).text(title).appendTo($div);
});
```

It's also worth noting that you can improve performance further by using `$.map()` to create an array of HTML strings which you append just once. This improves performance due to restricting the number of times the DOM has to be accessed per iteration.

```
var html = $.map(response.tests, (i, t) => `<div class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="${i}" /><label class="form-check-label">${t}</label></div>`);
$('#test_list').append(html);
```

Comment: So JSHint is telling me that `let` and `=>` are ES6. I am not used to these but I will look into them. The `map` method looks familiar from Python so I think I get that. Great response! I will look into it all! (and I will likely accept this answer)